# Is it possible to set MasterType programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

A page could have an attribute `MasterType` to make `Page.Master` to be strong-typed:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
```

If all my pages inherits specific class inherited `System.Web.UI.Page` itself, can I someway get access to `this.Master` property in it so I could call master page's methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your base class that all pages inherit from, just override the `Master` property, something like this:

```
public new SiteMaster Master
{
  get { return base.Master as SiteMaster ; }
}
```

or abatishchev's own variant:

```
public new ISiteMaster Master
{
  get { return base.Master as ISiteMaster; }
}
```